# Could not complete testing: fitnesse.slim.SlimError: Error SLiM server died before Header Message could be read

Tags: c#, .net, integration-testing, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am trying to integrate Fitness with Visual Studio 2022. Have .NET 6.0 installed. Following the instructions given in [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/25c78a/integration-testing-with-fitnesse/). However, every time I run the Test it throws the error

> Could not complete testing: fitnesse.slim.SlimError: Error SLiM server died before Header Message could be read. Unable to start test system 'slim': fitnesse.slim.SlimError: Error SLiM server died before Header Message could be read.

Looks like I am missing something very basic about Slim. Please let me know the resolution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. The Target Framework RunnerW was pointing to was incorrect. It was pointing to Dotnet4.8. I modified this. But, and included into the fitsharp solution. Then, building solution from Visual Studio kept failing. Identified that this needed updating the Nuget package. Updating kept skipping every time stating the package was already installed. Was unable to build because of these reasons. Was finally able to have breakthrough when I built the solution from cli. Running the Test after this was successful.